# Create a stemma codicum using qtree

Tags: forest, tikz-qtree, qtree

I've realized the following stemma codicum using forest.
[image]

However, I am trying to see if it is possible to recreate the same result using qtree. So far, I have managed to create the following code but as you can see from the picture the output is quite different. How can I fix it?

`\Tree [.$\Omega$ [. [$\Gamma$ ][V ]] [. [. [S ][F ]] [. [C ][L ]]]]`

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to see your original code for the `forest` item, to copy the sizes and other details over to `qtree`. Or even better (as customary on this site), if you could post a MWE with the `article` class, including the relevant packages and their settings, for easier replicability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the vertical lines by losing the brackets around the terminal labels, like this:

```
\Tree [.$\Omega$ [. $\Gamma$ V ] [. [. S F ] [. C L ]]]
```

To make the node dominating $\Gamma$ and V wider, and hence taller, you can artificially increase the width of $\Gamma$ like this:

```
\Tree [.$\Omega$ [. $\Gamma$ !\qsetw{6cm} V ]  [. [. S F ] [. C L ]  ]]
```

[image: best qtree option]

Qtree cannot produce a node with branches that end at different heights, so nodes $\Gamma$ and V will still be vertically even with each other. You’d have to simulate it by basically drawing that part of the tree with a low level graphics package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!